# Baking tables in cake php

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-bake

Im baking tables in cakephp. One table named abc which I baked successfully and I need to remove this table from database and also from the cakephp folder. I deleted all models, controllers, views and test fixture for that table. But due to some reasons now when Im baking my next tables it gives me an error "Missing database table 'abc' for model 'abc'. I dont know from where the error is coming. I deleted all files related to abc.

Comment: Baking questions belong on the cooking stackexchange site. It is dangerous to place your database server in an oven, you will definitely hurt the server and may start a fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting content of the `app/tmp/cache/models` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting all of the models in \app\models and then rebake them.

Comment: Kindly give an elaborate answer.